# What is the probability that the dj will play 3 songs in any order that is not consecutive?

Tags: probability

Every Monday morning from 0700-0800 hours, the radio disk jockey (dj) on duty
must play 8 songs on radio; the songs are pre-selected by his manager and the dj may
play any eight of them randomly.

The composition of songs selected for next Monday follows: 5 Jazz, 2 Soul, 10 R & B and 5 Country songs.

What is the probability that, on Monday next week, the dj will play three R & B songs in any order that is not consecutive?

I understand that we are choosing 3 songs that are R&B and then the rest but I'm getting confused with how to sort the problem without involving consecutive order.

The answer they gave : 0.1061

Comment: so two consecutive are acceptable?

Comment: The question never stated. I suppose it should be

Comment: I think that you should first calculate the chance that the DJ plays 8 songs that contain exactly 3 R&B songs (without account of order). Then you subtract the probability of those combinations that have these three songs consecutively. As @Alex mentioned, you have to also remove the combinations of two consecutive R&B songs if it is required by the question.

Comment: I think based on the "answer 'they' gave", no two consecutive songs should be from the R & B category.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are Perm(22,8) possible song orders if there are no restrictions.  To count the number of desirable song orders:

(a) Choose 3 R&B songs. (Order unimportant)

(b) Choose 5 other songs (Order unimportant)

(c) Choose 3 slots of 8 with no two consecutive (for the R&B songs).  (This can be counted by 'brute force', or by some sort of 'stars and bars' method)

(d) Choose an order for the R&B songs into their designated slots

(e) Choose an order for the other 5 songs into their designated slots.

Comment: Oh I got it. Thanks. $\frac{{(12P5)}{6\choose3}{(10P3)}}{22P8}$. Of the 12 that are not R&B, I chose 5 with order. From the 6 positions in between the 5 I chose 3 of them for the R&B songs to ensure they are not consecutive. Multiply that by 10P3 to order R&B choices and divide by 22P8 to get probability

Answer (score 0):

My attempt at this:

No. of ways of choosing 3 R&B and 5 non-R&B songs, let us say is $A = \binom{10}{3} \times \binom{12}{5}$

For each of the $A$ combinations, there are $8!$ unique sequences.

Out of these sequences, exclude those that satisfy the consecutive R&B condition. For this, visualise $3$ R&B songs joined together back to back as one song ($3!$ ways) and played together with the $5$ other songs ($6!$ ways). So total no. of sequences satisfying consecutive condition is $3! \times 6!$ ways.

So total no. of sequences acceptable (i.e., not satisfying consecutive condition) is $  \binom{10}{3} \times \binom{12}{5} \times (8! - 3! \times 6!)$

Total no. of all sequences is $_{22}P_8$

Probability is then

$  \frac{\binom{10}{3} \times \binom{12}{5} \times (8! - 3! \times 6!)}{_{22}P_8}$